# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client(closed)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, server, backend

I created one program that first i used res.status(200).send("some html code") then redirect

Here is example

```
app.get('/callback',async(req,res)=>{
 res.status(200).send("html code")
 res.redirect('/path/url')

})
```

Error

```
Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Remove line `res.status(200).send("html code")` entirely.

There's much confusion going on:

- Status code 200 implies there's no redirect, as a redirect would be 301 or 302.
- Calling `send` signals to the framework "I'm done here, send this stuff". You can't modify anything about the response after that. Sending a redirect would require you to send a different response.
- Sending content of any kind (such as the HTML you mention) on a redirect is not forbidden, but it is unusual, since most clients will just follow the redirect to get the actual content and pretty much ignore the content in the response.

In short:

- `res.status(200)` is pointless if you want to redirect, as that will change the status code anyway.
- `res.send("html code")` is not in itself a problem, but unusual and can probably be left out entirely.

Comment: i wanna redirect with display html code like when user comes to "/callback" then redirect with content different url it is possible ?

Comment: You *can* send content, I'm not sure if the browser will actually display it, but to be able to do that, simply remove the `status(200)` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/callback',async(req,res)=>{
 res.status(200).send("html code") //Remove this 
 res.redirect('/path/url')

})

app.get('/path/url',async(req,res)=>{
 res.status(200).send("html code") //put here 
})
```